# Using Selenium IDE to "Select" date from Ionic Input?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, ionic-framework, selenium-ide

Here's the code for the ionic component in question:

```
<IonInput
  name="startTreatmentDate"
  type="date"
  className={!startTreatmentDate ? 'hide-picker' : ''}
  id="date-picker"
  value={startTreatmentDate}
  spellCheck={false}
  autocapitalize="off"
  onIonChange={(e) => checkDateOfBirth(e.detail.value!)}
  required={true}
  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
/>
```

This item renders in the DOM as:

```
<ion-input name="startTreatmentDate" type="date" id="date-picker" value="" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="hide-picker sc-ion-input-md-h sc-ion-input-md-s md hydrated"><input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-0-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="startTreatmentDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="" spellcheck="false" type="date">
  ::before
  <input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-0-lbl"    autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="startTreatmentDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="" spellcheck="false" type="date">
</ion-input>
```

Below are the list of commands I'm currently using.
[image: Selenium IDE command list]

Expected:
Selenium IDE should accept click commands to select date from calendar.

Tried:
I've tried using the Selenium IDE Commands to click the input, and select a date; but the "Select" for the date gets registered as a keystroke rather than a click while recording. The click command also doesn't bring up the calendar for the date picker, so I can't even force the clicks by tracking their x/y and using that.

I've also tried using `execute script` to fire off JS to inject values, which only partially works, as it sets the inputs value without updating the value in the input itself (as pictured).

[image: Sets the value, but does not render in the input component]

I feel like I've tried just about everything short of trying to rewrite the input itself.